# Cron job — If computer inactive for x minutes turn wifi off

Tags: wifi, cron, monitoring, screensaver

I would like to have an alias command in my `.bashrc` that could be ran at startup. That states: If computer is inactive for X minutes then turn off wifi. How would I do that?

I am currently using netctl as my network manager. I already have an alias for turning my wifi off: `alias woff='sudo netctl stop network'`

But I'm not sure how I would do the if-then statement in my bashrc.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you define *idle*. If you're thinking of idle as being no user input, then you could write a script that monitors the output of:

```
xscreensaver-command -watch
```

which, according to it's man page:

> -watch  Prints a line each time the screensaver changes state: when the screen blanks, locks, unblanks, or when the running hack is changed. This option never returns; it is intended for use by shell scripts that want to react to the screensaver in some way. An example of its output would be:

```
BLANK Fri Nov  5 01:57:22 1999
RUN 34
RUN 79
RUN 16
LOCK Fri Nov  5 01:57:22 1999
RUN 76
RUN 12
UNBLANK Fri Nov  5 02:05:59 1999
```

The [man page](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man3.html) has an example script written in `perl` that may help you get started.

---

You could also take a look at the `batch` command, which is part of the `atd` suite.

From it's man page:

```
batch   executes commands when system  load  levels  permit;  in     other
       words,  when  the  load  average  drops below 0.8, or the value
       specified in the invocation of atrun.
```